# how to convert json string to datatable in c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Hi We are calling a webapi from c#. Getting json data. How to convert Json string to Datatable. I have read many posts suggesting to use a class, but my json string has `1024` columns...

How to convert Json `string` to `Datatable` without using a class

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json)
```

This didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have to deserialize it into DataTable, not Dataset :

`var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);`

Answer (score -1):

In your case you want to convert it into data table.

```
var resultDataTableHere = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(YourJsonResultHere);
```